# Relative Import Issue in Flask when Debug == True

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app that is running as a module. The structure looks like this

```
app/
  __init.py
  __main__.py
  app.py
  cli.py
```

`__main__.py` looks like this:

```
from . import cli
cli.main()
```

cli.py looks like this:

```
import argparse
import ConfigParser as configparser
import sys
from . import app


def command_line_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='application')

    parser.add_argument(
        '-c', '--config-file', type=str,
        help='Load settings from the chosen configuration file')
    return parser.parse_args()


    def main():
        "Run the app with the configuration chosen in command_line_arguments()"
        options = command_line_arguments()
        app = app.App(options.config_file)
        try:
            app.run(
                host=app.host,
                port=8000)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

The app runs fine, but if I try to set debug=true in the run parameters (or when initializing the app, I get the following error when I try to run the app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "" line 1, in <module>
    from . import cli
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Any ideas on how to get debug to work with this kind of a set up?

Comment: It should be `__init__.py` and not `__init.py`

Comment: You are running the file *directly* as a script (`python app/__main__`). Don't do that, run the package instead (`python -m app`). That'll only work if you rename your `__init.py` to `__init__.py` first.